# How can we increase the only font-size of text area

Tags: html, css

How can we increase the only font size of the text we write there , since my code is increasing the whole size of text area.

I was trying to make web sth like type tester but i am gettin stucked at this one thing because when i do font-size it increases the whole size of text area

#### HTML

```html
<textarea name="" id="mywords" cols="102" rows="20" placeholder=" START TYPING" ></textarea>
```

#### Css

```css
textarea{
    background-color: rgb(78, 94, 133);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(17, 197, 134);
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

PS. This is only part of the code.

Comment: `font-size` can be used but it might be increasing the entire size of the textarea because you have specified `rows` and `cols` for it. However you can resize the textarea using CSS for your desired size using `width` and `height`.

Comment: Could you describe what you want to happen when you increase the font size - are you decreasing the number of columns and rows to match? - or why not dispense with the cols and rows altogether and just set width and height?

Answer (score 0):

You may assign font size in `vw` for responsiveness across multiple devices.

```css
textarea {
      background-color: rgb(78, 94, 133);
      border-radius: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(17, 197, 134);
      font-size: 7vw;  // can't you make like this replace 7vw with  your expected value
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <textarea name="" id="mywords" cols="102" rows="20" placeholder=" START TYPING" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea{
    background-color: rgb(78, 94, 133);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(17, 197, 134);
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="mywords" cols="102" rows="20" placeholder=" START TYPING" ></textarea>
```

I played with the font-size of the textarea and realised that the textarea is adjusting itself depending on the number you put in `font-size`.

To fix that, you can either insert a lower number in `font-size`, or set a max height for your textarea:

```css
textarea{
    background-color: rgb(78, 94, 133);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(17, 197, 134);
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px


}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="mywords" cols="102" rows="20" placeholder=" START TYPING" ></textarea>
```

P.S: Notice that if you have a `max-height` and `max-width` set on your textarea, you can now have **really** large text if you want, as the maximum is no longer 100%.

Comment: I kinda did same but i used property tranform and made it !
Thanks bud it was helpful

Comment: @Ritikpanta Glad I could help! You can accept my answer if it did help ;)